# Developing 3d application with NDK beginner question

Tags: android, android-ndk

Im long time c++ developer . and I like to start to develop 3d applications and games for the android , now I do know I wil be limit with java VM 
So I like to start to develop with c++ with the NDK API , before I start , what version should I start to develop ? 2.3 ? can I do complete application just 
With c++ ? what problems should I expect ? can you please point me to articles on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a complete android application only using c/c++ code. But i would not recommend it due to the fact that you have to use android 2.3 or above and we all know that most android devices out there today, are likely to not ever receive the 2.3 update.

I would recommend you to use android 2.0, because android 2.0 have support for OpenGL ES 2.0 (only) in native code. The three limitations that i know is that you have to "start" your app in java code, you have to grab input in java code (not 100% sure of this) and you have to handle audio in java code. Although you can handle audio in native code if you are targeting android 2.2 and above, but again i would not recommend it since there is a lot of devices out there with 2.1.

Hope that answered some of your Q:s, sorry for tha bad English btw.

Edit: download the Android NDK and read trough the docs, that might clear more things up for you.